# UDP: Client started before Server

Tags: c++, visual-studio, networking, udp

I have a bit of a glitch in my game just now, everything runs fine if the server is started before the client however when the client is started before the server they never connect. This is all UDP

The problem happens when the client tries to call recvfrom() before the server has started, when this happens the client never finds the server and the server never finds the client. The resulted error is a wouldblock.

If I stop the client using recvfrom and start the client before the server (the client is still sending data its just not receiving it) they both find each other no problem.

Whats the solution for this? The way its seems just now is that the client cannot call recvfrom without a server being active or it all falls apart. Is there a check that can be done to see if data is sitting on a certain port(data the server would send)? Or is there a better way to do this?

Some Code...

Server Operation - UDPSocket is a class

```
    UDPSocket.Initialise();
    UDPSocket.MakeNonBlocking();
    UDPSocket.Bind(LOCALPORT);
    int n = UDPSocket.Receive(&thePacket);
    if (n > 0)
    UDPSocket.Send(&sendPacket);
```

Client...

```
    UDP.Initialise();
    UDP.MakeNonBlocking();
    UDP.SetDestinationAddress(SERVERIP, SERVERPORT);

    serverStatus = UDP.Receive(&recvPacket);    
    if (serverStatus > 0)
    {
        //Do some things
        UDP.Send(dPacket);  //Try and reconnect with server
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EWOULDBLOCK is not an error per se--it just means the socket was non-blocking and there was no data to read.  I presume your server listens for data and replies via UDP, and the client is sending a packet when it starts and receiving the reply?  If so, you may have a race condition anyway--what if the server is running but is just a bit slow, and you get EWOULDBLOCK in the client then?  Will your client just exit?  Perhaps you want to do a blocking receive in the client, or perhaps better yet, use `select()` or `WaitForMultipleEvents()` or TCP or something else.

Comment: The client and server are constantly sending data to a certain port (client connects to local IP just now) as mentioned this only breaks if the client is opened before the server. I cant understand why that causes no data to be ever received by the server or client

Comment: Some pseudo-code or minimal actual "broken" code would help here.  How your two programs interact is not entirely clear yet.

Comment: OK, so how about just not making the socket non-blocking?  Or at least letting it block until the first receive succeeds?  Or integrating select() or similar to actually get notified when data is available?  Your current scheme is fundamentally broken because it just hopes there will be data waiting without any real guarantee that there will be.

Comment: My understanding is that because its no blocking it will continue on checking that port for data and not hault the program. I still cant see how recvfrom is cauing this issue

Comment: Im going to poll the sockets with select() at least that way recvfrom wont be called when its not required. Thanks