# UDP Receiver needs to start before udp sender

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, gstreamer

I'm trying to send video from a raspberry pi 0w with camera running Raspian Buster to a machine running Ubuntu 18.04. I'm using ffmpeg to encode to h264 using hardware on the raspi end, and then sending the data with `gst-launch-1.0` over UDP. The issue is that if I start the raspi stream, and then start the receiver, the receiver never connects. If I start the receiver and then start the raspi stream, then they connect perfectly.

Raspi encode and send command:

`ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -c:v h264_omx -b:v 2000k -f avi pipe:1 | gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=3 fdsrc ! udpsink host=192.168.1.142 port=8090`

Receive and decode and display command:

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=8090 ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false`

I've looked at the `udpsink` and `udpsrc` properties and tried messing around with `buffer-size`, `blocksize`, and `sync` with no luck. I've also tried using `ffmpeg` from python to see if the issue was on the receiver side, with the exact same problem.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://127.0.0.1:8090',cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print('VideoCapture not opened')
    exit(-1)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print('frame empty')
        break

    cv2.imshow('image', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0XFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In the end, I might just write a small protocol that toggles the sender if no packets are getting through, but I was hoping that UDP would handle the connection better.

This question seemed simliar: [UDP: Client started before Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106036/udp-client-started-before-server) but didn't resolve my issue since I don't have any blocking ability with gstreamer/ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send SPS/PPS data periodically if you want to have random access. If you don't, this data will only get send in the very beginning. This information is critical for decoding a H.264 stream. Consider adding `h264parse` before the `udpsink` and configure it's `config-interval` property.

Comment: So I tried `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -c:v h264_omx -b:v 2000k -f avi pipe:1 | gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=3 fdsrc ! h264parse config-interval=1  ! udpsink host=192.168.1.142 port=8090` on the sender, and now it doesn't even connect if the receiver is started first. Is there a problem with piping data from ffmpeg to gstreamer? I also tried just using ffmpeg to send udp like `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -c:v h264_omx  -b:v 2000k -an -f  mpegts udp://192.168.1.142:8090` but the frames now arrive completely corrupted.

Comment: I haven't tried sending raw data for a long time. Perhaps you want to try to encapsulate the stream into RTP. In general it is a good idea to use one of the network protocols instead of sending raw.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Below is (slightly modified) your `ffmpeg` command

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -c:v h264_omx -b:v 2000k -an -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.142:8090?pkt_size=1316
```

that is wrapping video into [MPEG transport stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream).
Note that I've added `pkt_size=1316` at the end to force ffmpeg to do UDP transfer by sending equal packet sizes. That will help the receiver to catch up and not get overflowed.

To accept, demux and parse MPEG TS over UDP you can use GStreamer command

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=8090 \
! queue max-size-buffers=10000000 max-size-time=5000000000 max-size-bytes=20000000 \
! tsdemux name=demux \
demux.video_0_0100 ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

where `demux.video_0_0100` grabs demultiplexed video from MPEG TS by it's PID (ID of video as elementary stream). On receiver side, you can find out all details of your incomming stream, including PIDs, with command

```
gst-discoverer-1.0 -v -t 20 udp://0.0.0.0:8090
```