# Playing gstreamer udp stream in VLC

Tags: udp, gstreamer, vlc

I'm trying to play in VLC the next gstreamer pipeline form:

```
appsrc -> omxh264 -> h264parser -> mpegtsmux -> udpsink
```

In order to play it in VLC I setup the network stream source to:

```
udp://192.168.1.12@:5000/
```

The VLC only plays the video following the next sequence:

1) Start VLC player and open network connection, (remains on waiting status).

2) Start/play the gstreamer pipeline.

But if I try the other way around, i.e. start first the gstreamer pipeline and after VLC, it is not able to display the incoming udp video stream.

Ideally I need to play/start the gstreamer udp stream and open VLC any time I need to play/see the video.

Does anyone have any idea/clue why it's behaving like this?

Comment: Probably similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59676542/udp-receiver-needs-to-start-before-udp-sender/59683313

Comment: @FlorianZwoch thanks for pointing that out, but I already tried and unfortunately didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got it working, I had to setup the distance between two consecutive Intra frames (gop-length) greater than 0, now I can start VLC any time and it will play the video stream.